# PL/SQL procedure, cursor, PLS- 00103 ERROR

Tags: plsql, cursor, procedure

please, what is bad in this procedure. Mistake is PLS-00103 in 8,9 row

```
create or replace PROCEDURE test_one(l_f_name VARCHAR2,l_l_name VARCHAR2)
IS  
  CURSOR c1(f_name VARCHAR2,l_name VARCHAR2) IS 
    SELECT lastname,firstname
    FROM CUSTOMER;

  v_complex c1%ROWTYPE;
  f_name = l_f_name;
  l_name = l_l_name;

BEGIN
  open c1(f_name,l_name);
  fetch c1 into v_complex;

  dbms_output.put_line(v_complex.lastname|| '    ' ||v_complex.firstname);

  exit when c1%notfound;
  close c1;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assignment operator in PL/SQL is `:=`. Additionally type is missing in the local variable declaration (thanks to @Nitish). So valid code is:

```
f_name VARCHAR2(50) := l_f_name;
l_name VARCHAR2(50) := l_l_name;
```

Comment: BTW. From documentation: `The EXIT statement exits a loop and transfers control to the end of the loop.` But in your code there is no loop.

Comment: There are other errors too like declaration without type for `f_name` and `l_name`.

Answer (score 0):

Explicit cursors like this one are to be avoided in PLSQL.

It should be:

```
FOR v_complex IN c1(l_f_name, l_l_name) LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(v_complex.lastname|| '    ' ||v_complex.firstname);
END LOOP;
```

In which case you don't need to declare v_complex at all, or f_name, or l_name. Also, the cursor does not appear to actually use these variables. What are you trying to do?

This implicit cursor also avoids the need for explicit OPEN and CLOSE statements, you'll never get cursor leaks this way.

As for the actual problem, if the initialization is fixed, then your DBMS_OUTPUT should be after the %NOTFOUND check.